# How can I remove values from an array that are in another array without making a big long function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove values from an array that are in another array?

For example if I have these two arrays:

```
var arr1 = ["how", "can", "i", "remove", "values", "from", "an", "array", "that", "are", "in", "another", "array"];

var arr2 = ["can", "i", "an", "are", "in"];
```

How can I end up with:

```
["how", "remove", "values", "from", "array", "that", "another", "array"]
```

Without making some big long function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)?

Comment: Have you tried searching first for an answer before posting?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was looking for more of a one liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```js
var arr1 = ["how", "can", "i", "remove", "values", "from", "an", "array", "that", "are", "in", "another", "array"];

var arr2 = ["can", "i", "an", "are", "in"];

var arr3 = arr1.filter( function(a) {
    return arr2.indexOf( a ) == -1;
});
console.log( arr3 );
```